# Can I choose or influence the two kinds of transition animation while switching between desktops?

Tags: macos, desktop

Recently I noticed that there are two kinds of transition animation when switching between desktops.

- Sometimes the background picture slides with the desktop, and sometimes the background keeps still.

How can I set which transition animation to use using MacBook Pro, macOS Sierra?

Comment: I'm not seeing this. The only 2 transitions I get are 'slides intact from one to the other' or 'one slides out nicely, the other is totally black until after the transition, then pops into place'. 1st is done with Ctrl/numpad 2nd by Ctrl/arrow.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed it too and I have been looking everywhere to find a way to change the animation. I find the one with the fixed background way better than the classic one. A reddit user asked that question and posted a video of the effect, here's the link to the post: https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXTweaks/comments/5hv924/request_fixed_background_while_desktop_switching/?st=ixzu7113&sh=a3e1ddfb

Very interested if you have found something !

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.